# Extract multi-line javascript content from <script> tag using Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, regex, scrapy

I'm trying to extract data from this script tag using Scrapy:

```
<script>
        var hardwareTemplateFunctions;
        var storefrontContextUrl = '';

        jq(function() {
            var data = new Object();
            data.hardwareProductCode = '9054832';
            data.offeringCode = 'SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS';
            data.defaultTab = '';
            data.categoryId = 10001;

            data.bundles = new Object();
                            data.bundles['SMART_SUPERX.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('1099'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Super',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_PLUSS.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('1599'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('399'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Pluss',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('399'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('2199'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('299'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Basis',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('299'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_MINI.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('2999'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('199'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Mini',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('199'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['KONTANT_KOMPLETT.REGULAR'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('3499'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('0'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('0'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Kontant',
                    offeringType: 'PREPAID',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('0'),
                    commitmentTime: 0
                };

            data.reviewJson = new Object();


            hardwareTemplateFunctions = hardwareTemplateFunctions(data);
            hardwareTemplateFunctions.init();

            data.reviewSummaryBox = hardwareTemplateFunctions.reviewSummaryBox;

            accessoryFunctions(data).init();
            additionalServiceFunctions(data).init();
        });

        function parsePrice(str) {
            var price = parseFloat(str);
            return isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
        }

        var offerings = {};
    </script>
```

I wan to get the data from each section that looks like this:

```
 data.bundles['SMART_SUPERX.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                upfrontPrice: parsePrice('1099'),
                monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                offeringTitle: 'SMART Super',
                offeringType: 'VOICE',
                monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                commitmentTime: 12
            };
```

and then fetch the data from each field and get the final data from for example `upfrontPrice` (e.g 1099 in this example).

I have tried fetching each object using this:

```
items = response.xpath('//script/text()').re("data.bundles\[.*\](.*)")
```

However that only give me the first line of data. (`= {`). So how should i do this? Is there a better way of extracting this data from the script tag?

**Edit:** When i use `items = response.xpath('//script/text()').re("data.bundles\[.*\] = {((?s).*) };")` I seem to get only the last block (the one with `data.bundles['KONTANT_KOMPLETT.REGULAR']`)

How do i get a list of all of them?

Comment: By default in python regex `.` matches anything except newline. You can use for example `([^}]*)` - sequence of characters without `}`.

Comment: I was able to get the results by executing your javascript code using selenium (it needed some tweaks). The result is the `data` dict with all its members (including categoryId, etc). It will require Firefox installed on the server side for running the Javascript. Does it work for you?

Comment: @avenet i would like to not use selenium. However if you give me an example i will consider it. Also Is there a way to get the objects out a dicts without selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following regex seems to be correct:

```
r"data\.bundles\[[^\]]*\] = {([^}]*)}"
```

`*` in regexes is greedy - it will always try to match as much as possible, so i use `[^\]]` to make sure that I will match the closest `]`. I do the same with `{}` brackets. Additionally, I don't have to worry about `.` not matching newline.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to play around with regular expressions, there's [js2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/js2xml), which parses Javascript code and converts it to an lxml document.
Then you can use XPath to query things from the Javascript statements.
(disclaimer: I wrote and maintain js2xml)

Here's sample code on how to get those `data.bundles` assignments:

```
import scrapy

selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<script>
        var hardwareTemplateFunctions;
        var storefrontContextUrl = '';

        jq(function() {
            var data = new Object();
            data.hardwareProductCode = '9054832';
            data.offeringCode = 'SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS';
            data.defaultTab = '';
            data.categoryId = 10001;

            data.bundles = new Object();
                            data.bundles['SMART_SUPERX.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('1099'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Super',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('499'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_PLUSS.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('1599'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('399'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Pluss',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('399'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('2199'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('299'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Basis',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('299'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['SMART_MINI.TLF12PLEAS'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('199'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('2999'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('199'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('12'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Mini',
                    offeringType: 'VOICE',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('199'),
                    commitmentTime: 12
                };
                            data.bundles['KONTANT_KOMPLETT.REGULAR'] = {
                    signupFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    newMsisdnFee: parsePrice('0'),
                    upfrontPrice: parsePrice('3499'),
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('0'),
                    commitmentTime: parsePrice('0'),
                    offeringTitle: 'SMART Kontant',
                    offeringType: 'PREPAID',
                    monthlyPrice: parsePrice('0'),
                    commitmentTime: 0
                };

            data.reviewJson = new Object();


            hardwareTemplateFunctions = hardwareTemplateFunctions(data);
            hardwareTemplateFunctions.init();

            data.reviewSummaryBox = hardwareTemplateFunctions.reviewSummaryBox;

            accessoryFunctions(data).init();
            additionalServiceFunctions(data).init();
        });

        function parsePrice(str) {
            var price = parseFloat(str);
            return isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
        }

        var offerings = {};
    </script>""")
```

(this first part is to get the HTML input in a Scrapy Selector)

```
import js2xml
import pprint

data_bundles = {}
for script in selector.xpath('//script/text()').extract():
    # this is how you turn Javascript code into an XML document (lxml document in fact)
    jstree = js2xml.parse(script)

    # then, we're interested in assignments of data.bundles object
    for a in jstree.xpath('//assign[left//property/identifier/@name="bundles" and right/object]'):
        # the assigned property is give by a <string> property from a <bracketaccessor>
        bundle_prop = a.xpath('./left/bracketaccessor/property/string/text()')
        if bundle_prop is not None:
            curr_prop = bundle_prop[0]

        data_bundles[curr_prop] = {}

        # the left object is assigned an object (inside a <right> element)
        # let's loop on the <property> elements)
        # the values are either numbers or string arguments of a function call
        for prop in a.xpath('./right/object/property'):
            data_bundles[curr_prop][prop.xpath('@name')[0]] = prop.xpath('.//number/@value | .//string/text()')[0]

pprint.pprint(data_bundles)
```

This is what you get out of this:

```
{'KONTANT_KOMPLETT.REGULAR': {'commitmentTime': '0',
                              'monthlyPrice': '0',
                              'newMsisdnFee': '0',
                              'offeringTitle': 'SMART Kontant',
                              'offeringType': 'PREPAID',
                              'signupFee': '0',
                              'upfrontPrice': '3499'},
 'SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS': {'commitmentTime': '12',
                            'monthlyPrice': '299',
                            'newMsisdnFee': '199',
                            'offeringTitle': 'SMART Basis',
                            'offeringType': 'VOICE',
                            'signupFee': '0',
                            'upfrontPrice': '2199'},
 'SMART_MINI.TLF12PLEAS': {'commitmentTime': '12',
                           'monthlyPrice': '199',
                           'newMsisdnFee': '199',
                           'offeringTitle': 'SMART Mini',
                           'offeringType': 'VOICE',
                           'signupFee': '0',
                           'upfrontPrice': '2999'},
 'SMART_PLUSS.TLF12PLEAS': {'commitmentTime': '12',
                            'monthlyPrice': '399',
                            'newMsisdnFee': '199',
                            'offeringTitle': 'SMART Pluss',
                            'offeringType': 'VOICE',
                            'signupFee': '0',
                            'upfrontPrice': '1599'},
 'SMART_SUPERX.TLF12PLEAS': {'commitmentTime': '12',
                             'monthlyPrice': '499',
                             'newMsisdnFee': '199',
                             'offeringTitle': 'SMART Super',
                             'offeringType': 'VOICE',
                             'signupFee': '0',
                             'upfrontPrice': '1099'}}
```

For more info on the XML schema you get with  `js2xml.parse()`, you can check https://github.com/redapple/js2xml/blob/master/SCHEMA.rst

Answer (score 3):

This script requires [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [python-selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) installed, also I made the tests using a file called script.txt, which contains the script surrounded by  tag. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

script_content = open("script.txt").read()

#Removing script tags
exec_script = script_content.replace("<script>", "").replace("</script>", "")

#Removing jq function call
exec_script = exec_script.replace("jq(function() {", "").replace("});", "")

#Setting some helper functions to avoid javascript errors
helper_functions = """function hardwareTemplateFunctions(){
                     return {init: function(){}};};  
                     accessoryFunctions = additionalServiceFunctions = 
                     hardwareTemplateFunctions;"""

#Returning data variable
return_statement = "return data;"

wd = webdriver.Firefox()

#Getting data variable in result
result = wd.execute_script(helper_functions + exec_script +  return_statement)
```

The result variable looks like this:

```
{u'bundles': {u'KONTANT_KOMPLETT.REGULAR': {u'commitmentTime': 0,
   u'monthlyPrice': 0,
   u'newMsisdnFee': 0,
   u'offeringTitle': u'SMART Kontant',
   u'offeringType': u'PREPAID',
   u'signupFee': 0,
   u'upfrontPrice': 3499},
  u'SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS': {u'commitmentTime': 12,
   u'monthlyPrice': 299,
   u'newMsisdnFee': 199,
   u'offeringTitle': u'SMART Basis',
   u'offeringType': u'VOICE',
   u'signupFee': 0,
   u'upfrontPrice': 2199},
  u'SMART_MINI.TLF12PLEAS': {u'commitmentTime': 12,
   u'monthlyPrice': 199,
   u'newMsisdnFee': 199,
   u'offeringTitle': u'SMART Mini',
   u'offeringType': u'VOICE',
   u'signupFee': 0,
   u'upfrontPrice': 2999},
  u'SMART_PLUSS.TLF12PLEAS': {u'commitmentTime': 12,
   u'monthlyPrice': 399,
   u'newMsisdnFee': 199,
   u'offeringTitle': u'SMART Pluss',
   u'offeringType': u'VOICE',
   u'signupFee': 0,
   u'upfrontPrice': 1599},
  u'SMART_SUPERX.TLF12PLEAS': {u'commitmentTime': 12,
   u'monthlyPrice': 499,
   u'newMsisdnFee': 199,
   u'offeringTitle': u'SMART Super',
   u'offeringType': u'VOICE',
   u'signupFee': 0,
   u'upfrontPrice': 1099}},
 u'categoryId': 10001,
 u'defaultTab': u'',
 u'hardwareProductCode': u'9054832',
 u'offeringCode': u'SMART_BASIC.TLF12PLEAS',
 u'reviewJson': {},
 u'reviewSummaryBox': None}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer as well. I ended up not using it, but it is a neat solution for a future project. :)