# How can I extract a javascript value in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl youtube videos and I need the language of title/description of the video.When I use browser view source on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH-zVXN8OMg) I can inside a script tag there is a variable `'METADATA_LANGUAGE': 'no'`. Can I extract this value in scrapy and its extensions or I should download and parse html with libraries like beautifulsoup / htmlparser.

Comment: If you want content generated by javascript look at Selenium. It uses a browser to get the finall rendered html which can be given back to scrapy for scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794967/6240631) you can select the text of script with xpath/css and then use regex to search the variable name. Assum the first script contains the `METADATA_LANGUAGE`:

```
items = response.xpath('//script/text()')[0].re(".*METADATA_LANGUAGE.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using Scrapy. You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754760/extract-multi-line-javascript-content-from-script-tag-using-scrapy).

There are many ways to achieve what you're looking for. One is to get the `<script>` tag using scrapy's selectors and then use [regex](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) to get the specific `METADATA_LANGUAGE` variable you're looking for.