# Scrapy - get the value of Javascript variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Using Scrapy, how do I get value of a Javascript variable ....

Here is the my code ...

```
<script rel="bmc-data">
      var match = 'yes';
      var country = 'uk';
      var tmData = {
        "googleExperimentVariation": "1",
        "pageTitle": "Child Care",
        "page_type": "claimed",
        "company_state": "wyostate",
        "company_city": "mycity"
                   };
</script>
```

I want to check the value of **page_type** variable. If its "**claimed**" process the page, or else move on ....

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791059/how-can-i-extract-a-javascript-value-in-scrapy#36794967) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754760/extract-multi-line-javascript-content-from-script-tag-using-scrapy)

**I have tried this ...**

```
pattern = r'page_type = "(\w+)",'
response.xpath('//script[@rel="bmc-data"]').re(pattern)
```

but ofcourse this is not working, becuase I think my regex is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest using [`js2xml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/js2xml) for this (disclaimer: I wrote js2xml)

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> import js2xml
>>> html = '''<script rel="bmc-data">
...       var match = 'yes';
...       var country = 'uk';
...       var tmData = {
...         "googleExperimentVariation": "1",
...         "pageTitle": "Child Care",
...         "page_type": "claimed",
...         "company_state": "wyostate",
...         "company_city": "mycity"
...                    };
... </script>'''
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=html)
>>> selector.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first()
u'\n      var match = \'yes\';\n      var country = \'uk\';\n      var tmData = {\n        "googleExperimentVariation": "1",\n        "pageTitle": "Child Care",\n        "page_type": "claimed",\n        "company_state": "wyostate",\n        "company_city": "mycity"\n                   };\n'
>>> jscode = selector.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first()
>>> jstree = js2xml.parse(jscode)
>>> print(js2xml.pretty_print(jstree))
<program>
  <var name="match">
    <string>yes</string>
  </var>
  <var name="country">
    <string>uk</string>
  </var>
  <var name="tmData">
    <object>
      <property name="googleExperimentVariation">
        <string>1</string>
      </property>
      <property name="pageTitle">
        <string>Child Care</string>
      </property>
      <property name="page_type">
        <string>claimed</string>
      </property>
      <property name="company_state">
        <string>wyostate</string>
      </property>
      <property name="company_city">
        <string>mycity</string>
      </property>
    </object>
  </var>
</program>

>>> jstree.xpath('//var[@name="tmData"]/object')[0]
<Element object at 0x7f0b0018f050>

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> data = js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(jstree.xpath('//var[@name="tmData"]/object')[0])
>>> pprint(data)
{'company_city': 'mycity',
 'company_state': 'wyostate',
 'googleExperimentVariation': '1',
 'pageTitle': 'Child Care',
 'page_type': 'claimed'}
>>> data['page_type']
'claimed'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul, Using a library for this simple operation seems bit of an overkill ...

Comment: Depends on the use-case obviously. Personnally, if I can avoid writing regex, I prefer. Matter of taste maybe.

Comment: seems to be a line missing. It should have
jstree = js2xml.parse(jscode)

Answer (score 5):

Your regex pattern is faulty here:

```
# you are looking for this bit: "page_type": "claimed",
re.findall('page_type": "(.+)"', html_body)
# ["claimed"]
```

Or in the context for scrapy Selectors in your case:

```
response.xpath('//script[@rel="bmc-data"]').re('page_type": "(.+)"')
```

If you need to parse more than one variable like this I recommend answer mentioned by Paul, since regex is not always as reliable as xml parsing.

Comment: Thanks, I got this error when I tried your solution ... `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'findall'`

Comment: @PuneetSharma it seems like you have some syntax issues, see my edit for a concrete example for your case.